# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Upsert affected multiple rows

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

When i try to login into game play services inside my app in android with specific email ID in my phone, i'm getting the following error. But same ID is working in other devices within my app.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[1]

Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 21525

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Upsert affected multiple rows
    at bzx.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):25)
    at bzx.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):19)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.provider.PlayGamesContentProvider.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):538)
    at bzx.insert(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):4)
    at qus.insert(:com.google.android.gms@19831028@19.8.31 (100400-284611645):4)
    at android.content.ContentProviderOperation.apply(ContentProviderOperation.java:297)
    at bzx.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):14)
    at bzx.applyBatch(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):3)
    at dvk.applyBatch(:com.google.android.gms@19831028@19.8.31 (100400-284611645):3)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.applyBatch(ContentProvider.java:344)
    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:474)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:1705)
    at cxs.b(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):29)
    at czv.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):279)
    at czv.b(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):22)
    at cxy.c(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):2)
    at dzo.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):7)
    at dzr.a(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):4)
    at bkv.run(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):1)
    at cdz.b(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):15)
    at cdz.run(:com.google.android.play.games.services@144480040@2019.11.14448 (284081242.284081242-000400):10)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at tfn.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Suppressed: gmi: 
    at tk_trace.games-PlayGamesSignInIntentService_onStartCommand(Unknown Source:0)
```

Comment: Same problem here, since a few hours ago.

Comment: Same here, since yesterday!

Comment: If I installed the app on my Personal Area (I'm a Samsung owner) it works correctly

Comment: After wiping Play Games and Play Service data from the device. It now works again correctly!

Comment: @MassimilianoNegro but we can't expect all our users to manually swipe the data to make it works again. I hope Google will fix this on their side quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem since friday.

Any login attempt returned INTERNAL_ERROR (8)

Wiping all data of Play Games and Play Services as MaxDevJS suggests in the comments above got it working again.